# can PHP know details of ALL PHP environment just now?

Tags: php

using sys_getloadavg() we can get server load,
using memory_get_usage() we get MEM asigned to THIS_script.php

however:
is possible some similar to this program using PURE code PHP (not shell, not bash):

```
<?php
function get_ALL_process_PHP_running_just_now(){
    ...
    ...
    ... get memory of ALL process PHP
    return array_process_number();
    }
```

then obtain some similar to:

total scripts running: 35

users running process: 6

process with more of 5 minutes: 2

memory GLOBAL asigned to all process PHP: 8GB
etc...

is possible obtain that info with "admin.php" ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is no build-in function that pieces together that data, however the functions you refer to (`sys_getloadavg`, `memory_get_usage`) are just wrappers around the `/proc` filesystem (on linux anyway, i don't think too many of them have windows counterparts).

The ordinary filesystem functions, which you use to read files, can be used to read the `/proc` filesystem, which in turn contains all the information you might want.

Comment: thanks @Raxi, the function `memory_get_usage()` give that info, but ONLY for "this_script.php", not about global environment PHP.